Django + FactoryBoy -> Postgres not converting datetime to utc correctly
Okay, this is a weird one. I've got a Django model that I'm writing to Postgres via FactoryBoy for testing.
contract = ContractFactory(        
    effective_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
)

I'm in US/Central, and I expect the database to store the object in UTC. The datetime in Postgres should be 2023-01-01 06:00:00 UTC since the difference between timezones is 6 hours.
If I fetch the object back and print the date, it's wrong!
2023-01-01 05:51:00+00:00

If I fetch it from Postgres directly, it's also wrong:
2023-01-01 05:51:00.000000 +00:00

I checked the raw time in the database and it's correct. Postgres is running in a Docker container, and if I do a select now() the time is just fine in UTC.
Where could this be coming from?

This indicates to me something else is in the mix. To your question add as text the following: 1) Is there a trigger on the table that could be changing the value? 2) What is the table definition in the database? 3) What are the time zone settings in the Django conf file?

Found the answer here: unexpected results converting timezones in python
Using the datatime function to build the time doesn't work. It requires creation of the datetime and then localization after.
